# DATETIME losing hh:mm when changing CREATE TABLE to SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, splunk-query

I am currently migrating all of my company's reports into Splunk Data Labs input for ingestion. The reports create temp tables using the CREATE TABLE format, which is incompatible with Splunk, however, SELECT INTO format works just fine.

The error that I am getting however when changing to the SELECT INTO format, is the DATETIME variable which should be MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm format loses the hh:mm end, and instead shows MM/DD/YYYY MM/DD/YYYY:

Original SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Stats#(date_slice DATETIME NULL, raw_value REAL NULL)
INSERT INTO #Stats#
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), data_datetime, 111) + ' ' +
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, data_datetime) < 30 THEN
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':00' ELSE
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':30' END AS date_hour
        ,SUM(ship_qty) AS moves
    FROM #tmpAllData
    GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(11), data_datetime, 111) + ' ' +
        case when DATEPART(minute, data_datetime) < 30 THEN
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':00' ELSE
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':30' END
    ORDER BY 1
```

Modified SQL:

```
--CREATE TABLE #Stats#(date_slice DATETIME NULL, raw_value REAL NULL)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), data_datetime, 111) + ' ' +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, data_datetime) < 30 THEN
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':00' ELSE
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':30' END date_slice
    ,SUM(ship_qty) raw_value
INTO #Stats#
FROM #tmpAllData
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(11), data_datetime, 111) + ' ' +
    case when DATEPART(minute, data_datetime) < 30 THEN
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':00' ELSE
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(str(DATEPART(hour, data_datetime))), 2) + ':30' END
ORDER BY 1
```

- Original Output: "07/12/2018 10:00:00  "
- Modified Output: "2018/07/12 2018/07/12"

Comment: You should be careful not to order by ordinal position. And in this case it is doing nothing but making your query slower. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second statement is creating the temporary table `#Stats` without any preset column definitions. It instead creates the columns based on the return data type of the `SELECT`

This means that the SQL Server is not reading the output in question as a `DATETIME` but instead as a `STR`.

I would try to use a `CONVERT` in your modified statement to see if you get different functionality.

It sounds like this question is mostly for your curiosity so I will add that the original statement is the standard way to accomplish what you've outlined.

This is because `SELECT`... `INTO` statements are harder to read and revise for new users and because they can lead to some unexpected functionality as you have displayed above.

Comment: Thanks, Edward, for your response. I assumed that without definitions, it would use the same data type as what is being selected? If that were the case, it is DATETIME in the actual database.

Comment: Ed, I apologize, after sectioning off the code, I've found that it is actually pulling the correct data. Later on in the query is when it actually does the SELECT for everything that is displayed to the user in the end. I've got it narrowed down now lol. This has been frustrating. I'm taking SQL queries that are as long as a college essay and breaking them down to work in Splunk for ingestion.

Comment: So I am not 100% on the rules the database engine uses to determine datatype, but generally I would expect it to output as as `string` when left undefined since you used the `STR()` function in your `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, similar to what Edward had said. The query I had posted was returning a DATETIME data type, however, at the very end of the query when it selects all information to display to the user, it got converted to CHAR somewhere in between, so I just converted it to DATETIME before converting to CHAR and splitting up the values.